# STDERR.reopen() thows an error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, stderr

I'm trying to write to the standard error file for my test case:

```
STDERR.reopen("err","w")
```

but it fails giving the following error:

> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_io_reopen - err

I can't seem to make out what might be the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - this works as expected (using JRuby on Windows). Do you have permissions to create a file in your current working directory?

Comment: I am using ruby 2.3.1 on Windows10.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you don't have write access to the current directory (or to the file "err" if it already exists).

Depending on your requirements, you might want to use a file in the temp directory instead:

```
STDERR.reopen("/tmp/err","w")
```

Comment: I have the write access to the current directory.

Comment: Does the file "err" already exist in this directory? Does File.new("err", "w") work?

Comment: "err" exists in the directory. I'm able to write contents to the file.